# Union info from 2 connected tables

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 2 table in my firebird database

Table with questions:

```
| qsn_id | qsn_text |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | Qsn1     |
| 2      | Qsn2     |
```

Table with answers:

```
| ans_id | ans_text | qsn_id |
|--------|----------|--------|
| 1      | Answer1  | 1      |
| 2      | Answer2  | 1      |
| 3      | Answer1  | 2      |
| 4      | Answer2  | 2      |
```

Is there any query to get info like this:

```
| Text    |
|---------|
| Qsn1    |
| Answer1 |
| Answer2 |
| Qsn2    |
| Answer1 |
| Answer2 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `order by`:

```
select text
from ((select q.qsn_text as text, q.qsn_id, 0 as ans_id
       from questions q
      ) union all
      (select a.ans_text, a.qsn_id, a.ans_id
       from answers a
      )
     ) qa
order by qsn_id, ans_id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
text
----
Qsn1
Answer1
Answer2
Qsn2
Answer1
Answer2
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a742f7/3

Answer (score 0):

You could also run **EXECUTE BLOCK**

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
RETURNS (Text VARCHAR(100))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE qsn_id int;
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT
    question.qsn_id,
    question.qsn_text
  FROM question
  ORDER BY question.qsn_id ASC
  INTO :qsn_id, :Text DO
  BEGIN 
    SUSPEND;

    FOR SELECT
      answers.ans_text
    FROM answers
    WHERE answers.qsn_id = :qsn_id
    ORDER BY answers.ans_id ASC
    INTO :Text DO
    BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
    END
  END
END
```

You can modified **EXECUTE BLOCK** to **STORED PROCEDURE** by replacing `EXECUTE BLOCK` to `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ProcedureName`.

If you created **STORED PROCEDURE** you must than call SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM procedurename
```

Output is:

```
TEXT
--------
Qsn1
Answer1
Answer2
Qsn2
Answer1
Answer2
```